# Elements duplicated with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is the url: [https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster"](https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster%22)

If I run this command:

```
soup.find_all('span', class_="sidearm-roster-player-height")
```

then I try to get the length of the output, it is mentioned 20 while it is supposed to be 10.

I can't see why this happens.

Comment: more than likely it's because the information is repeated when you click on an individuals name

Answer (score 0):

Change your class selector as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('.height')])
```

---

Note: You can grab the whole table with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster')[2]
print(table)
```